# Include path for XCode6 Beta

Tags: swift, xcode6

`Swift` has portions of `Darwin` implemented, for instance, this works:

```
import Darwin
rand()
```

Where does `XCode6` store the underlying include files for this? I wanted to add in `scanf` functionality the same way they added in `rand()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you type "rand()" in a Swift notebook, do Jump to Definition in Xcode (CMD-CTRL-J), it will take you to the Swift header for the C standard library.

I believe you can see there all the C standard library functions where Apple has provided a Swift API. But you can't see the Swift implementation, since I don't think that's supplied. I would guess it's compiled into the Swift framework.

But what you asked is where that header file is located. Here's how to find it:

1. Create a Swift command-line application, and use the rand() function.
2. Build it.
3. In the Report Navigator, expand all the underlying command-line build commands, to look for the paths that were passed to the compiler.

If you look at the paths in the link phase, you may find something at `/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx`
.

But I don't think Swift is using a plaintext file format for the headers, and I think the headers only give you access to C's standard lib because there's also a compiled Swift wrapper layer in between, or some kind of bridging header, so it may not be easy to just add missing functions at this point.